# How to execute a block statement in C# for Firebird

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I am trying to delete all tables in a database in Firebird using the following command:

```
string dropAllForeignKeysSql =
  "EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS (stmt VARCHAR(1000)) AS "+
  "BEGIN "+
  "FOR "+
  "select 'alter table \"'||r.rdb$relation_name ||'\" drop constraint '||r.rdb$constraint_name||';' "+
  "from rdb$relation_constraints r "+
  "where (r.rdb$constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY') "+
  "into :stmt "+
  " DO begin execute statement :stmt; end "+
  "END "+
  ";";

using (var connection = sessionFactory.OpenSession().Connection)
  {
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = dropAllForeignKeysSql;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Unfortunately, the command is not executed. However, when I pause the debugger, copy the string in the `CommandText` variable and execute the query manually/ not in code, the statement is executed. If I replace the CommandText with a simpler command like `DROP TABLE myTable`, then this command IS executed in the code, i.e. the table is deleted. No error is thrown when running the code (in contrast to when I intentionally enter a wrong command or open the database in an external tool).

From there, I conclude that the error is not in the SQL statement and not in the command setup and not in having set up a wrong connection. Where else could the error be?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you need to remove the semicolon(`;`) at the end of your dynamically constructed query. Semicolons are not part of Firebird's query language.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the reason. Executing query string that is generated works fine (with and without semicolon).

Comment: Have you tried adding newline characters to each concatenated line? Is there any way to trace actual sql query executed by ExecuteNonQuery on database server?

Comment: Yes, but this has no influence on the outcome.

Comment: The problem might also have to do with the fact that the column `rdb$relation_name` is a CHAR(31) and therefor padded with spaces. Try to use `TRIM`.

Comment: No luck here. I've trimmed every variable like `trim(r.rdb$relation_name)`. The query executes fine in the DB tool with all spaces

Comment: Do you have all the exceptions turned on while debugging?

Comment: You mean the Exceptions settings in VS? I checked all "Thrown" and "User-unhandled"

Answer (score 0):

You should use FbBatchExecution

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbTransaction fbt = fbc.BeginTransaction(); // object fbc is your FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection

FirebirdSql.Data.Isql.FbBatchExecution fbe = new FirebirdSql.Data.Isql.FbBatchExecution(fbc);
fbe.SqlStatements.Add(dropAllForeignKeysSql); // Your string here

fbe.Execute(true);

fbt.Commit();
```

And change 'term' before begin script:

```
SET term #;
```

Comment: When I execute this, I get the error `The type of the SQL statement could not be determinated.` Removing the SET TERM statements results in `Batch execution aborted
The returned message was: Execute requires the Command object to have a Transaction object when the Connection object assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the Command has not been initialized.` This message strangely disappears and the code runs fine when omitting the transaction, but in this case the constraints again are not be deleted.

Comment: What's the Firebird engine version?

Comment: Firebird client 3.0.2.1 for Ado.NET, Firebird 2.5.2.26539-0 Win32 as embedded engine and Firebird 2.5.2.26539 Win32 when using the server version

Comment: @Dani: Do you remember the cause for the transaction error message above? I'm having exactly the same issue here. (2.5.3.26778.ds4-5)

Comment: @lenniep I'm afraid, no; we abandonned the statement approach :-|