# Firebird Execute Statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, firebird

I am trying to insert multiple rows into a firebird table by using an execute block. But I get an error saying that "term" is invalid.

```
"Dynamic SQL Error nSQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 5 term"
```

Here is the C# code that I use for the insert

```
connection.Open();
string insertData = "set term ^ ; execute block as begin;";

foreach (dataPoint dataPointInsert in dataPointList)
{                      
    insertData += string.Format(" insert into data (trip_id, trip_type, longitude, latitude, speed, date_time, heading, valid) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}','{6}',{7});",
                                  dataPointInsert.GUID, dataPointInsert.tripType, dataPointInsert.longitude, dataPointInsert.latitude, dataPointInsert.speed, dataPointInsert.dateTime, dataPointInsert.heading, Convert.ToInt32(dataPointInsert.valid));
}

insertData += " end^";

var createCommand = new FbCommand(insertData, connection);
createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I was trying to replicate the example on the firebird website [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq336/).

I am using firebird version 2.5.2 and Firebird ADO.NET Data provider 4.1.5.0

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_20_adonet.html

Comment: No I haven't. Do you think the newlines in the command are necessary?

Comment: Looks like it's a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293135/how-to-execute-a-block-statement-in-c-sharp-for-firebird

Comment: @Graymatter it isn't: `set term` simply is not part off the firebird syntax (it does exist in client tools like isql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't (in fact you shouldn't, because it's a client side command, Firebird doesn't understand it) have to use `set term` because `FbCommand` and Firebird itself (in protocol) can execute only one query in a "batch".

So create *just* your `execute block` statement and you're fine.

Comment: I ended up doing an execute block, but ran into the problem that a statement cannot be bigger than 64KB I think. I ended up separating my statements into blocks of 50000 characters and it works great now. Entering about 10000 records in 2 seconds now.

Comment: Yes, there's bunch of limitations on size. Most visible is probably the one you're mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use set term ^;

just end your code with ^

if you DO HAVE TO set term to ^, put it back with set term ;^